# 12 or 16 column grid for a full width website like pinterest/vevo.com

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive-design, fluid-layout

So I'm looking for the right answer for my grid system:

1) Should I use 12 or 16 column grid for a full width website like:

```
http://xfinitytv.comcast.net
http://pinterest.com
http://www.vevo.com
```

2) Can I use bootstrap3 for 16 width

3) what are the challenges for a 16 columns grid vs traditional 12 column grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> paulmars,its upto you and your design.you can use both 12 column and
>   16 column grids. yes you can use bootstrap it will give you the css
>   for layout as well as all the components needed with
>   javascript.Bootstrap is a nice choice.

Comment: thanks @hell_rider. Could I have your thoughts on websites like xfinitytv.comcast.net and vevo.com that uses full browser width: can we tell they are using 12 or 16 columns? Which grid system and framework would work better for sites like that? thanks.